# Menu with dynamically spaced text to cover entire width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="menu">
 <a href="#">Home</a>
 <a href="#">Products</a>
 <a href="#">Contact</a>
 <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
```

The width of the div is 1500px (but might adjust as this is a responsive design).

What I want is to have `Home` align completely left of the div and `About` to align completely right of the div, everything in between needs to be evenly spaced.

How would you do that?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Answer (score 4):

You could use css3 justify content to achieve that goal:

```
.menu {
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pn1f3hrq/2/

but you should take in consideration browser support.

css-tricks posted an article which explains how to implement for optimal browser support:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

Comment: This works great, i'm wondering if there is anyways to increase browser support even more.